# how to find a cyclic matrix.

Tags: matrices

I need help in knowing how to find a cyclic matrix. By cyclic matrix, I mean one that when you raise it to the power of n it will eventually be back to its original matrix. An example that I have been given is \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1\\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
when you raise that to the power of n you will get a repeating pattern of 6 matrices. I want to know how I can find another matrix that works the same.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I was looking into the exact same problem just recently, and the normal way of doing this is to diagonalise the matrix, so that you write $A=P^{-1}DP$, where D only has entries in the first and fourth spaces, and notice that if you raise this to the power of n, you get $A^n=P^{-1}D^nP$, and $D^n$ is very easy to calculate

Answer (score 1):

The $n$th power of the $n \times n$ matrix

```
0 1 0 ... 0 0 
0 0 1 ... 0 0
...
0 0 0 ... 1 0
1 0 0 ... 0 0
```

will be the identity matrix, so its $(n+1)$st power will be itself.

If you want $2 \times 2$ matrices that repeat after powers consider the rotation matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
- \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for $\theta = 2\pi/n$.

Comment: These are not the only examples though, any matrix whose diagonal form has entries of absolute value 1 will be cyclic